# should I move from caliburn to caliburn.micro

Tags: caliburn.micro, caliburn

I'm developing an infrastructure for a major project currently based on caliburn 1.

It works fine but it seems like the future is in caliburn micro, am I right? 
If I do, how do I implement filters? How do I specify view to a view viewnodel (non conventional)?

And whats the best place to put my splash logic (not root model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend moving to Caliburn.Micro as it's simpler and easier to extend. It is where any future innovations will be made and it has a larger more active community. As far as filters go, you can actually build them and plug them in. See here [Marco's post](http://marcoamendola.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/a-caliburn-micro-recipe-filters/) You can add non-conventional view specification as well. You just plug into the view locator and teach it how to find views. For example, if you want to use an attribute, you can just have the locator look for that attribute first, use it if found, otherwise fall back to the default behavior. Regarding splash logic, you can do that by customizing the Bootstrapper.